# How to get section content from another site with multisite setting

Tags: templating, craft3

I have a multisite on Craft 3 and I was wondering how to get section content from another site? Let's say I'm on a default site and I want to get contact content from site with handle siteA?

Can this be done?

Comment: Of course, just include the siteId in your elementQuery. I'm currently on my smartphone so it's difficult to provide code but it should look like
`$site = Craft::$app->sites->getSiteByHandle('your-handle');` and in your query you include `$elementQuery->siteId = $site->id`

Comment: That's a perfectly good answer - thank you @Anubarak ! I was wondering if this is possible on the frontend using craft.entries.section? I was wondering about this approach: 

craft.entries.section('sectionHandle').relatedTo(...)  - and this is where I'm stuck, because in theory I can pass an array with sourceSite attribute.

When I looked in the source code, there's indeed an option to do that. 

I've a section that's enabled for site with handle "default" and id = 1

I'm querying this like this: 

`craft.entries.section('jobs').relatedTo({ element: craft.entries, sourceSite: 1}); `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a template you could do:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('jobs').site('siteA').all() %}
```

In your follow up comment, you're passing `craft.entries` as an element to `relatedTo`, but that's just going to be an instance of the `ElementQuery` class.  You need to give it the actual element you're interested in finding the relationship to.

Comment: Thanks Brad, that's very helpful! I also found another way: 

`{%set entries = craft.entries({ section: 'jobs', siteId: 2}).all() %}`

Downside is, that I need to retrieve id not use handle.