# Multisite Craft 3, different entries on different sites

Tags: entries, craft3, multi-site

Is it possible to show different entries on different subsites?

Currently I can show different versions of the same entry (e.g. translations), but I want entry 1 to show on site 1, entry 2 on site 1, entry 3 on site 2, etc.

As I have different user accounts for the admin for each site, is it also possible to only show the entries for site 1 in the cms of site 1?

In total I'd like to create around 30 subsites.

**Update - site setup**

I'm working with only 1 locale. I have one primary (default) site, the rest is in the same group, all on a different base URL and handle.

Comment: Maybe this post is related, but I can't figure out how to post an entry only for site 1: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22426/how-to-get-section-content-from-another-site-with-multisite-setting

Comment: Can you update your question to describe how you have Sites and Locales setup? In Craft 3, both Sites and Locales get grouped under Sites, so if you have a situation where you need to differentiate between them both in your templates you may need to setup a Custom Translation Method on your fields. I believe we discussed Custom Translation Methods toward the end of this hangout (https://straightupcraft.com/events/managing-multiple-sites-in-craft-3-sites-and-localization). They do take a moment to wrap your head around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, this was fixed in [3.0.0-RC15](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/a3cc52f0f13b3bd7288e599571adf5da0d70cc69)

> Added the “Propagate entries across all enabled sites?” section setting. If disabled, entries will only be associated with the site they were created on.